# In IE11, clicking on next or back button opening a new page using intro.js

Tags: javascript, intro.js

If I use the arrow keys it works fine. But if I click on the next or back button opening a new page

I am using setOptions like below:

```
setOptions({
    steps:[{
        element: '#cmsinput', 
        intro: 'ENTER URL HERE', 
        position:'bottom'
    }],
    'showStepNumbers': 'false'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this problem because introJs considers the tour complete for this page. The Done button runs the code in your oncomplete function. You can change the text of the Done button using the doneLabel option.

`doneLabel: 'Next Page'`